# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I want to make a calculator in tkinter with input from the user.
However, I can't do it because it has a 'NoneType' object error.

```
A = Label(janela, text = "A=",)
A.place( x = 220, y = 70)
a = StringVar
caixa_de_escrita_a = Entry(janela, textvariable = a, width = 25, bg = 
"lightgreen").place(x=250, y= 70)
B = Label(janela, text = "B=")
B.place(x=220 , y = 85) 
b = StringVar
caixa_de_escrita_b = Entry(janela, textvariable = b, width = 25, bg = 
"lightgreen").place(x=250, y =``85)

 c = int(caixa_de_escrita_a.get())
 d = int(caixa_de_escrita_b.get())
```

Error:

```
c = int(caixa_de_escrita_a.get())
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Comment: Looks like `place` returns `None`. Maybe you meant to set your `caixa` variables to the `Entry` objects instead of to the return value of `place`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `place` returns `None`. Maybe you meant to set your `caixa` variables to the `Entry` objects instead of to the return value of `place`.

Like this:

```
caixa_de_escrita_a = Entry(janela, textvariable=a, width=25, bg="lightgreen")
caixa_de_escrita_a.place(x=250, y=70)
... 
caixa_de_escrita_b = Entry(janela, textvariable=b, width=25, bg="lightgreen")
caixa_de_escrita_b.place(x=250, y=85)
```